# how to get String value from other generated equivalent string

Tags: java, string

How it will print welcome using following `System.out.println`.
Generated will give `ac`. But how should I make it as `welcome` (that ia ac value not `"ac"`)

```
public class BrowserSample {

  public static void main(String[] args) {    
    String generated = "ac";
    String ac = "welcome";
    System.out.println("value from generated is = " + generated);
  }
}
```

Comment: change `System.out.println("value from generated is = "+generated);` into `System.out.println("value from generated is = "+ac);`

Comment: Your Question is not clear. generated will print ac as the string ac is assigned to it. If you want to print ac, then do : `System.out.println("value from ac is = "+ac);`

Is this what you are asking for ? If not let us know what your intention is ?

Comment: You can't find a random string in memory and change it based on what it contains.  Can you give an example of what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: generated string will be randomly assigned, so i need the value of string which contained generated text.

Comment: do assign value like  generated=ac; before sysout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok After a brief experiment here is the solution you want

```
String generated = "ac";

String ac = "welcome";  // declare as member of class

String s = (String) getClass().getDeclaredField(generated).get(this);
```

s will contain `welcome`

Answer (score 1):

What about a map, key-value pair.

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
String generated = "ac";
map.put("ac","welcome")
System.out.println("value from generated is = "+map.get("ac"));
```

And what you are expecting that is not possible and also meaningless.